# How do I go about creating 'spurs' in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, lettering

[image: bmc monogram]

Hello everybody, just wanted some help in creating the pointy things on the letters as demonstrated on the image. Thank you

Comment: Draw triangles.

Answer (score 2):

Draw half the shape with the Pen Tool, copy it, and reflect it, and group both together. Then copy and paste this wherever you need it.

Example

[image]